# Mapping and Cauchy- Reimann conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, vector-fields, analytic-functions

If a complex function is analytic it must hold Cauchy-Reimann Conditions, So conjugate of F(Z) is irrotational and solenoidal , Does this points mapping from $R^2 $ to a subspace of $R^2 $  ($R^1 $) , if F(Z) maps to $R^2 $ we dont get a divergent less field , But the above interpretation does not satisfy idea of conformal mappings , can any one correct me?